# My selector has maximum specificity but still isn't being applied. Why not?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am trying to target an element with specific class inheritance. When using Chrome Dev tools, I see that the style is as specific as it gets and still it is crossed out and not being used.

[image: screenshot]

I am using SASS and the following code:

```
.post-item, .post-type-project, .project, .type-project {
    .post-text {
        width: calc(35% - 15px);
    }
}
```

I don't want to use the `!important` hack, because it breaks other CSS rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to verify that your code is placed lower in the compiled file. Otherwise try to strengthen the weight of your selector by an id (for example):

```css
#parentContainer{ 
  .post-item, .post-type-project, .project, .type-project {
    .post-text {
      width: calc(35% - 15px);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer and @AwsmeSandy 's answer provide a workaround, but don't really explain why the OP's selector is being overwritten.

Comment: this is not a workaround. in CSS each selector has a weight that sets priority for selectors that target the same element. if two selector have the same poind the one that writes the lowest in the style file will apply

Comment: OP specifically asked why his selector wasn't being applied. The answer is 'because there's another, more specific, selector being applied over it'. The first approach should be to increase the specificity of the target selector *without* adding to markup. Sometimes that's not possible, and you have to add a new class or ID.

Answer (score 4):

As a quick primer on CSS specificity in general, you can use the base-10 method to calculate the "weight" of a rule.

```
elements & pseudo-elements =    1
classes & pseudo-classes   =   10
id's                       =  100
inline                     = 1000
```

So in this example, the first rule in your scenario is:

```
0 elements & pseudo-elements =    1 * 0 =    0
5 classes & pseudo-classes   =   10 * 5 =   50
0 id's                       =  100 * 0 =    0
0 inline                     = 1000 * 0 =    0
                                  TOTAL =   50
```

Calculating your rule, you've got a specificity of 30 (3 classes). In order to take precedence it needs to have a value greater than 50 (or exactly 50 and be declared after the other rule).

While you can add a single ID to the list, and it will bump up the specificity high enough to override the first rule, you are also limiting the rule to only one specific location. While you've avoided using the `!important` flag, you've introduced another issue.

Consider the you are trying to make sure a door is locked, but have this rule:

```
house door.exterior {
    state: unlocked;
}
```

Alice isn't home, and you want to make sure Alice's door is locked, so you specify:

```
#alice door.exterior {
    state: locked;
}
```

When Bob and Carol aren't home:

```
#carol door.exterior,
#bob door.exterior,
#alice door.exterior {
    state: locked;
}
```

We've accomplished locking the doors, but we've both added a maintenance issue and obscured the reason for locking the doors. We'd need to add the rule for every person whose house we want to lock. We would be much better off by using a lower specificity rule that is semantically significant.

```
house.owner-away door.exterior {
    state: locked;
}
```

CSS is often a balancing act between too specific and not specific enough. In this case the rule you're trying to override has 2 semantic classes that are overriding your rule, it specifies that it applies to posts in a `post-list` and only applied to `post-text` that follows a `post-image`. If these rules also apply to your rule, use them, if not, look around and see what other more general rules you can use.

**Note** While the base-10 method is an easy way of representing relative specificity, a single selector at each level will override any number of selectors at the next. For example, having 11 element selectors does not override 1 class, even though this method will calculate it at a higher value.

Answer (score 1):

do it like this, increasing the nesting by adding one more item

```
body{
.post-item, .post-type-project, .project, .type-project {
  .post-text {
    width: calc(35% - 15px);
  }
}
}
```

or

```
body .post-item, body .post-type-project, body .project, body .type-project {
  .post-text {
    width: calc(35% - 15px);
  }
}
}
```